# Stanford Training Lambda Too Big

Tags: lambda, stanford-nlp, part-of-speech

I am using Stanford POS Tagger to train a corpus. I prepared the settings file "Prop" and formated the data and started the training.

After that, i started getting messages like "Lambda Too Big" and these messages kept occurring until the end of the training. I tried the model after and kept giving me an "Out of Memory Exception". I tired the model on a HPC which have over 40gb of RAM and increased the heap space of java to use 25gb but the same problem still occurring.

The corpus i use have about about 6000 sentences, the minimum number of words in a sentence are the 3 and the max are 128 words. A word could have three tags at the same like {p1}{p2}.

When i start the training, here are the logs:

```
 pcond initialized
 zlambda initialized
 ftildeArr initialized
QNMinimizer called on double function of 337720 variables, using M = 10.

Iter. 0: neg. log cond. likelihood = 821394.2976644086 [1 calls to valueAt]
          An explanation of the output:
Iter           The number of iterations
evals          The number of function evaluations
SCALING        <D> Diagonal scaling was used; <I> Scaled Identity
LINESEARCH     [## M steplength]  Minpack linesearch
                   1-Function value was too high
                   2-Value ok, gradient positive, positive curvature
                   3-Value ok, gradient negative, positive curvature
                   4-Value ok, gradient negative, negative curvature
               [.. B]  Backtracking
VALUE          The current function value
TIME           Total elapsed time
|GNORM|        The current norm of the gradient
{RELNORM}      The ratio of the current to initial gradient norms
AVEIMPROVE     The average improvement / current value
EVALSCORE      The last available eval score

Iter ## evals ## <SCALING> [LINESEARCH] VALUE TIME |GNORM| {RELNORM} AVEIMPROVE
EVALSCORE

Iter 1 evals 1 <D> [lambda 5525 too big: 623.532051211901
lambda 28341 too big: 623.5660256059567
lambda 153849 too big: 623.5660256059567
```

Also, here are the settings used in the prop file:

```
## tagger training invoked at Thu Mar 03 01:31:10 AST 2016 with arguments:
                   model = arabic.New.tagger
                    arch = words(-2,2),order(1),prefix(6),suffix(6),unicodeshapes(1)
            wordFunction = 
               trainFile = format=TSV,Train.txt
         closedClassTags = 
 closedClassTagThreshold = 40
 curWordMinFeatureThresh = 1
                   debug = false
             debugPrefix = 
            tagSeparator = /
                encoding = UTF-8
              iterations = 100
                    lang = arabic
    learnClosedClassTags = false
        minFeatureThresh = 3
           openClassTags = 
rareWordMinFeatureThresh = 3
          rareWordThresh = 5
                  search = qn
                    sgml = false
            sigmaSquared = 0.0
                   regL1 = 0.75
               tagInside = 
                tokenize = false
        tokenizerFactory = edu.stanford.nlp.process.WhitespaceTokenizer
        tokenizerOptions = 
                 verbose = false
          verboseResults = true
    veryCommonWordThresh = 250
                xmlInput = 
              outputFile = 
            outputFormat = slashTags
     outputFormatOptions = 
                nthreads = 1
```

Can anybody tell me what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

With regards to Lambda size message, you can find an answer here: [Lambda Size is Too Bog](https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/java-nlp-user/2015-February/006800.html)

With respect to `Out Of Memory Exception`, please spcifiy the size of the file you want to tag. Whatever the case, I suspect that you are trying to pass a large file for the tagger. Try to pass a file of `100 KB` as a test. I don't think that you will get an error message if the size of your file is small. However, if the `Out Of Memory Exception` error message keeps showing, then you can post a question to `java-nlp-user` here: [java-nlp-user](https://mailman.stanford.edu/mailman/listinfo/java-nlp-user). Kindly notice that you have to subsribe to the list before posting any question.

I hope this helps you!

Comment: I will try your suggestion and post back...Thanks.